# String of strings for arbitrary amount, python

Tags: python

Say we have a list whose elements are string items. So for example, `x = ['dogs', 'cats']`.

How could one go about making a new string `"'dogs', 'cats'"` for an arbitrary number of items in list x?

Comment: How would you treat items that contain the `'` character?

Comment: In particular: Are you happy treating them exactly the same way that Python's `repr` function does (basically, that means replacing the outer quotes with double quotes if that's sufficient, backslash-escaping quotes if not), or do you want different rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str.join` and `repr`:

```
>>> x = ['dogs', 'cats']
>>> ", ".join(map(repr,x))
"'dogs', 'cats'"
```

or:

```
>>> ", ".join([repr(y) for y in x])
"'dogs', 'cats'"
```

Comment: Thank you, this works for me. Still trying to figure out difference between repr and str.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the following:

```
', '.join(repr(s) for s in x)
```

Answer (score 1):

For this special case, this is ~17 times faster than `", ".join()`

```
>>> x = "['dogs', 'cats']"
>>> repr(x)[1:-1]
"'dogs', 'cats'"
```